# Convergent or divergent ??

Tags: real-analysis

I have a general term $A_n = 1- (1 + 1/2^n)^p$ and the question is whether $\sum A_n$ is diverging or converging, so I applied the D alembert's ratio test where I found $A_{n+1}/A_n$ is greater than unity thus $\sum A_n$ should be diverging but my answer disagrees with the book answer which says its converging so where did I go wrong ?(p is a natural number)

Comment: Is $p$ any real number?

Comment: How did you show that $A_{n+1}/A_n$ in the limit is $>1$?

Comment: What are the conditions on p?

Comment: On I forgot to mention p should be a natural number

Comment: It actually converges for any real $p$.

Comment: Well I assumed that $A_{n+1}/A_n > 1$ and proceeded accordingly

Comment: @ArnavDas: Why would you assume that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm if I assume that then i get $1- (1+1/2^{n+1})^p > 1-(1+1/2^n)^p$ thus breaking this down I eventually get $(1+1/2^{n+1})^p < (1+1/2^n)^p$ which is true enough.... Isn't it ??

Comment: @ArnavDas: Yes, you can get anything you want if you start by assuming something that _is not true_. But you don't learn anything by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... when $n$ is large, $1/2^n$ is small, and therefore $(1+1/2^n)^p \sim 1^p+p\frac{1}{2^n}$ because $\left(\frac{d}{dx}x^p\right)_{x=1} = p$. Thus, for large $n$ we should have
$$ 1-(1+1/2^n)^p \sim \frac{-p}{2^n} $$
and the right-hand side obviously sums to a finite number.

To put these rough estimates back on a rigorous track, you should be able to squeeze your series between $\sum \frac{\pm 2p}{2^n}$ when $n$ is high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let we consider positive terms $a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^p-1$.

Since $\log(1+x)$ is a concave increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $e^x-1$ is a convex increasing function, for any $n\geq \log_2(p)$ we have:

$$ a_n = \exp\left(p \log\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right)-1\leq e^{\frac{p}{2^n}}-1\leq \frac{p(e-1)}{2^n}$$
so $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a summable sequence by comparison with the geometric series.

You may also prove that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a decreasing and convex sequence by noticing that $a_n>0$ and by computing $\frac{d}{dn}\,\log(1+a_n)$ and $\frac{d^2}{dn^2}\log(1+a_n)$.